# How to create a Vercel Cron job for getStaticProps in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, cron-task, getstaticprops

I have a NextJS website that has 6-7 API that needs to be called every 24 hours. Earlier I was using ISR with revalidation but [someone suggested using Vercel's cron job](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/136i6sj/how_exactly_the_isr_works/).

I need to set it up so that the `getStaticProps` function is triggered every 24 hours and I'm really struggling to find something related to that (documentation and articles ask me to create an API route.) How exactly can we set up a cron job with Vercel, The website is currently hosted at Netlify. Do I need to host it on Vercel?